# Chaining multiple parallel asynchronous workflows

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I am a C# developer interested in learning F#. I have a simple AWS lambda function that is triggered when a user uploads new file (or files) to the S3 storage. Each file is then parsed and its contents are sent to an API gateway.

The code is basically functional, but I am struggling to chain all the asynchronous functions together. So far, I have been (mis)using `Async.RunSynchronously` to get a proof of concept. Here is the code of the main function:

```
namespace MyProject

open Amazon.Lambda.Core
open Amazon
open Amazon.S3
open Amazon.S3.Util
open System.IO
open Amazon.S3.Model
open Amazon.SecretsManager.Extensions.Caching


[<assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof<Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer>)>]
()

type Function() =    
    member __.FunctionHandler (input: S3EventNotification) (_: ILambdaContext) =        
        async {
            use client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.EUWest1)
            use secretsCache = new SecretsManagerCache()

            // ApiClient.authenticate: SecretManagerCache -> Async<string>
            // Sends a POST request to the API in order to obtain an authentication token
            let! token = ApiClient.authenticate secretsCache

            // ApiClient.getExistingIds: SecretManagerCache -> Async<string[]>
            // Gets a list of already existing IDs from the API
            let! existingIds = ApiClient.getExistingIds secretsCache

            // input.Records is a C# List<S3EventNotificationRecord>
            for record in input.Records do
                // MyParser.processFile: AmazonS3Client -> S3EventNotificationRecord -> Async<MyJsonModel list>
                // Downloads the actual contents of the file specified in the S3EventNotification
                // and parses it using an FSharp.Data.JsonProvider into individual items
                let! json = MyParser.processFile client record

                // Split the items into a list that should be updated and a list that should be created
                let (putList, postList) = json
                                |> List.partition (fun item ->
                                  Array.contains item.Id existingIds)
                
                for item in putList do
                    // ApiClient.putLocation: string -> SecretsManagerCache -> MyJsonModel -> Async<unit>
                    // Tries to PUT an item and writes the result into logs
                    ApiClient.putLocation token secretsCache item
                    |> ignore

                for item in postList do
                    // ApiClient.postLocation: string -> SecretsManagerCache -> MyJsonModel -> Async<unit>
                    // Tries to POST an item and writes the result into logs
                    ApiClient.postLocation token secretsCache item
                    |> ignore
        } //??? What to put here? Async.RunSynchronously?
```

To put the code into words:

1. Firstly, I need to obtain an authentication token for the API.
2. Then, I need to get a list of already existing items (or their IDs) from the API.
3. Next, I load and parse each of the uploaded files. This can be done in parallel (probably using `Async.Parallel`)
4. Each file produces a list of items, which is then split into a list for updating and a list for creating.
5. All the items from the `putList` and the `postList` are then sent to the API. The result of each request is logged. Both lists can also be processed in parallel.

The thing that I struggle most with is how to "attach" POSTing and PUTting of the parsed items to the actual parsing, if all operations are done using `Async.Parallel`. Also, do I need to add a single `Async.RunSynchronously` to the very end of my  `FunctionHandler`, or will it be executed even without this statement?

Lastly, I am already calling a couple of `Async.AwaitTask` functions to convert the C# `Task<T>` objects provided by the `AmazonS3Client` and `SecretsManagerCache` objects. Does `Async.AwaitTask` simply convert `Task<T>` to `Async<T>`, or does it somehow change the flow of the asynchronous computation?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you need to move the two `use` lines inside of `async`, otherwise those objects will be destroyed before `async` even starts

Comment: Thanks for the warning :) I will update my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should use an async signature since it does long processing as per the [aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-handler.html):

```
member __.FunctionHandler ... : Threading.Tasks.Task<'T>
```

You can do so by finishing your async with

```
async {
   return true
}
|> Async.StartAsTask
```

Inside your function you can use Async.Parallel every time you have `Seq<Async 'T>` and need a `Async<'T[]>`. In your case you have `Seq<Async<unit>>` so you need to ignore the result with `Async.ignore`.

```
async{

do!   putList
      |>Seq.map (ApiClient.putLocation token secretsCache)
      |>Async.parallel
      |>Async.ignore

...
}
```

The processing of input records can also be parallelized, if you wrap all the procesing into an `Async<unit>` function just like I've shown above for the putlist and putlocation.